# How to design a Python class that inherits from a type determined at instantiation?

Tags: python, autocomplete, option-type, python-typing

I'm trying to design a Python class called `Try`, which takes one or more `Option[T]` types as constructor arguments. `Try` should inherit all of its attributes and functions from the first non-`None` value among its arguments, which can be of any type. For illustration, let's suppose `T` is `str`.

Here's an example of how I'd like to use `Try`:

```py
t = Try('my string' if random.random() > 0.5 else None)
```

In this case, t should be an instance of `Try` that inherits all attributes and functions from `str`. I want to be able to chain functions and attributes on `t`, and eventually resolve it to either `str | None` using the `into` attribute:

```py
t = Try('my string   ' if random.random() > 0.5 else None).rstrip()
print(t.into)  # will print either 'my string' or 'None'
```

What's more, I want `Try` to inherit the auto-completion and syntax highlighting on its attributes and functions as though it could be treated just like the type it's option is typed to.

Here's my current attempt at implementing this class:

```py
from typing import Any, Generic, Optional, TypeVar

T = TypeVar('T')

class Try(Generic[T]):
    
    def __init__(self, option: Optional[T]) -> None:

        self.into = option
        self.internal_type = type(option) if option is not None else None

    def __getattr__(self, name: str) -> "Try[Any]":

        return Try(getattr(self.into, name, None))
    
    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs) -> "Try[Any]":

        if callable(self.into):
            return Try(self.into(*args, **kwargs))
        return Try(None)
    
    def __dir__(self):
        return dir(self.internal_type)
```

I added the `__dir__` function in an attempt to get the class to inherit the auto-complete and syntax highlighting for functions and attributes of its contained class, but it doesn't work.

Can someone help me fix my implementation or suggest a better way to implement this `Try` class in Python? Any tips or pointers in the right direction would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: If the argument is `None`, you *still* want to inherit from (or at least delegate attribute lookup to) `str`. This isn't really a job for inheritance. The purpose of a class is to define a uniform interface for *all* values of the class, regardless of the *particular* value.

Comment: Unlike Haskell, where a value like `Nothing :: Maybe String` still provides information about the *intended* type, `None` does not imply an "underlying" type to bind to `T`.

Comment: @chepner So do you suggest that I instantiate a dynamic type using `type(x, y, z)` with a function call rather than a class?